# How to use Mapper.cs with Instasharp

Tags: c#, instagram, instasharp

I'm a french student and I have to do a project for the semester.
I have to get medias from Instagram (with the api) and put them in a database. I use instasharp for now and I can do a request with the HttpClient class.

This returns a string with the content of the JSON request. But I've seen a class named Mapper.cs, which should match the result of the request with the different class of instasharp.
For example, if I search for a media, the mapper class should read the JSON string a create an appropriate instance of Media.
I do this kind of request: https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=45.759723&lng=4.842223&distance=5000&client_id=My-Id&count=5

But I'm not sure of it, is somebody able to tell me what the Mapper class really does.

---

Here is the Mapper class, I do not understand all of the method, so I can't use it.

```
 class Mapper {
    public static object Map<T>(string json) where T : new() {

        //var t = new T();
        var j = JObject.Parse(json);
        var t = typeof(T);

        try {
            var instance = Map(t, j);

            // add the pure json back
            if (instance != null) {
                var prop = instance.GetType().GetProperty("Json");
                if (prop != null) {
                    prop.SetValue(instance, json, null);
                }
            }

            return instance;

        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static object Map(Type t, JObject json) {

            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

            Array.ForEach(instance.GetType().GetProperties(), prop => {

                var attribute = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Model.JsonMapping), false);

                if (attribute.Length > 0) {
                    var propertyType = prop.PropertyType;
                    var mapsTo = ((Model.JsonMapping)attribute[0]).MapsTo;
                    var mappingType = ((Model.JsonMapping)attribute[0]).MapType;

                    switch (mappingType) {
                        case Model.JsonMapping.MappingType.Class:
                            if (json[mapsTo] != null) {
                                if (json[mapsTo].HasValues) {
                                    var obj = Map(propertyType, (JObject)json[mapsTo]);
                                    prop.SetValue(instance, obj, null);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case Model.JsonMapping.MappingType.Collection:
                            var col = Map(propertyType, (JArray)json[mapsTo]);
                            prop.SetValue(instance, col, null);
                            break;
                        default:
                            if (json != null) {
                                if (json[mapsTo] != null) {
                                    // special case for datetime because it comes in Unix format
                                    if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
                                        prop.SetValue(instance, UnixTimeStampToDateTime(json[mapsTo].ToString()), null);
                                    else
                                        prop.SetValue(instance, Convert.ChangeType(json[mapsTo].ToString(), prop.PropertyType), null);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });

            return instance;
    }

    private static IList Map(Type t, JArray json) {
        var type = t.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        // This will produce List<Image> or whatever the original element type is
        var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type);
        var result = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);

        if (json != null) {
            foreach (var j in json)
                if (type.Name == "String" || type.Name == "Int32")
                    result.Add(j.ToString());
                else result.Add(Map(type, (JObject)j));
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime(string unixTimeStamp) {
        // Unix timestamp is seconds past epoch
        double unixTime = Convert.ToDouble(unixTimeStamp);
        System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTime).ToLocalTime();
        return dtDateTime;
    }

    private static void SetPropertyValue(PropertyInfo prop, object instance, object value) {
        prop.SetValue(instance, Convert.ChangeType(value, prop.PropertyType), null);
    }
}
```

And that is what I tried, but it doesn't work, "Erreur  540 'InstaSharp.Mapper.Map(string)' is not accessible" (something like this, I translated the error myself)

And this one "Error 539 The type or namespace name 'media' is not found ( a using directive or an assembly reference is it missing ?"

```
InstaSharp.Model.Media media = new InstaSharp.Model.Media();

InstaSharp.Mapper.Map<media>(reponse);
```

I really don't know how to use the Mapper class because I never saw a class like that (I started to use C# only 6 month ago)

Comment: Please post the code for the Mapper class, and show what you've already tried.

Comment: [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The `Map<T>` method is expecting a type, so the type of `media`, not the instance `media`. Your usage should be something like:

```
InstaSharp.Mapper.Map<InstaSharp.Model.Media>(response);
```

As for what the class does, it exposes one static method `Map<T>(string)` and looks like it uses JSON.net to deserialize the string parameter into an instance of the type `T` with data values mapped from the JSON.

If you wanted a `List<T>` of `Media`, you'd do much the same thing as before:

```
InstaSharp.Mapper.Map<List<InstaSharp.Model.Media>>(response);
```

Lastly, because the result of `Map<T>` is an `object`, you'll need to cast it or use a `dynamic` variable to actually do anything.

```
var x = (List<Model.Media>)Mapper.Map<List<Model.Media>>(response);
```

To specify what class properties map to what json property, you'll need to add the `Model.JsonMapping` attribute to your properties and specify the `MapTo` attribute option.

```
[Model.JsonMapping(MapTo="someJsonProperty")]
public string SomeProperty {get;set;}
```

Comment: Tanks you that seems to work (the method  was not accessible so i put "public" before "class Mapper" does it matter?).
But now how can i put all of the result in a media list for exemple? I've seen that the method Map return that thing:

 var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(t); 

But i have no idea how i could make this a list of Media.

Comment: I did as you said:

 List<InstaSharp.Model.Media> mylist = InstaSharp.Mapper.Map<List<InstaSharp.Model.Media>>(reponse);

But i have an error about type.

Error 589 Can not implicitly convert type ' object ' to ' System.Collections.Generic.List < InstaSharp.Model.Media >' . An explicit conversion exists (cast iron is non - missing it ? )

Comment: You need to cast the result, see answer for updates.

Comment: Ok thank you, but now i have another problèm (sorry for asking you so much questions).
I've tried many types in the Map method but it's always empty, i've serched in the map method code and i found that this line never enter in the loop:

if (json[mapsTo] != null)

can you see the code of the Mapper class below? It should be easier for you to see what i'm talking about

Comment: Looks like `Map<T>` requires you add attributes to your `Model.Media` class's properties. See last update

Comment: Where should i put this code? I put it in the class Model.Media  and i get this error: "Error 8 ' mapsto ' is not a valid attribute named argument. Attribute arguments must be named fields that are not readonly , static, constant , or read-write properties that are public and not static"
Moreover should i change the word "myProperty" you put?

Comment: Listen, I'm trying to be helpful but if you're not going to do a bit of leg work yourself, I can't help you. I never typed 'mapsto' and C# is a case-sensitive language, so you need to type exactly `MapTo`. You put the attribute on the properties you want to map to and specify what JSON property you're mapping it to.